# I was wondering what is wrong with my java code here. The button is meant to open a new window, but it doesn't

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

When I run my app, everything is fine, except when the button is clicked nothing happens.
Here is my java and xml along with screenshots

```
package xyz.gregswebsite.notes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class note_taker extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    Button advanceToTaker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    advanceToTaker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(note_taker.this, anther_class.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

and here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="xyz.gregswebsite.notes.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="You have no notes"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    android:id="@+id/button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

here are the screenshots:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQGGN.jpg
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9nYr.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can u post anther_class code as well?

Comment: have you set the correct content?  `setContentView(R.layout.content_main);` must be the same where thu button is...

Comment: @Raghavendra its just a test class with nothing in it, is that where the new window should be located?

Comment: post your manifest.xml

Comment: have you declare your second activity in manifest file.

Comment: @GJCOD : did you include anther_class declaration in your manifest file ?

Comment: no i didnt, i have edited the question and included the mannifest file.

Comment: you haven't described any of those activities in manifest.xml

Comment: you did not included your second activity `anther_class` in manifest file

Comment: check your logcat, it must be saying that, "Hey mention this activity in manifest first" something like that

Comment: check my answer

Comment: First, use correct name for class like `NoteTaker` or `AntherClass`. Then, since both activity are not in your manifest, your `note_taker` won't even show .. so I don't know what you are running here. For me, you have a MainActivity class somewhere with the same layout but you are working on the wrong class

Comment: where is the note_taker Activity mentioned on manifest?

Answer (score 1):

You are using note_taker activity and i could find that in your xml posted,

```
tools:context="xyz.gregswebsite.notes.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
```

Why this?

Correct your xml with the right activity context and try run.

Comment: Got the same conclusion. OP is working on a class (`note_taker`) but the activitiy shown in the app is an other (`MainActivity`). I used manifest for this. Not sure `tools:context` won't let you use the layout (never really check how they worked)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <activity
        android:name=".anther_class"/>
 <activity
        android:name=".note_taker"/>
</application>
```

Comment: that didnt help, I get the same outcome.

Comment: did you get any crash?

Comment: no, its just that nothing happens when i tap the button.

Comment: put  a debug point near this line Intent intent = new Intent(note_taker.this, anther_class.class); and check whether this is getting executed or not

Comment: also it says that the "anther_class" is not assignable.

Comment: i get,"the activity must be exported or contain a debug filter.

Comment: @GJ COD , can you update your answer and post your another_activity class  ?

Comment: click on your java folder->choose your package->right click on your pakage->new->activity->basicActivity

Comment: after doing this.replace your anther_class.java with new class created

Comment: was this helpful?

Comment: in that Activity->Basic Activity